# Convert String to Int Column in Pandas Csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, type-conversion

Halo, im newbie using python

First of all, i want to ask about convert string to array. I have a 6 data training and 2 data testing.

There is a 1 method called a nilaiPrediksi()

nilaiPrediksi means a convert a 'Hepatitis A' to '1' and 'Hepatitis B' to '-1'

before that, i already make a nilaiTarget() and successfull.  but in file i only wrote '1' and '-1' , not 'Hepatitis A' and 'Hepatitis B'
here is my succesfully code, before i change my some data in csv:

```
target = df.loc[:5, "Klasifikasi"]
targetPrediksi = target.sort_index(ascending = False)
targetPrediksi.index=range(len(targetPrediksi))

nilaiTarget = pd.concat([target, targetPrediksi], axis =1)
nilaiTarget
```

> [image]

here is my dataset
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lRmd4oErkTPixiuvxdumSvtbmgCndS_x

```
df = pd.read_csv("datalatihnodummy.csv", sep=';')
target = df.loc[:5, "Klasifikasi"]
```

> [image]

here is my code of nilaiPrediksi() after i add 'Hepatitis A' and 'Hepatitis B'

```
def nilaiPrediksi():
    df = pd.read_csv("datalatihnodummy.csv", sep=';')
    target = df.loc[:5, "Klasifikasi"]
    targetPrediksi = target.sort_index(ascending = False)
    targetPrediksi.index=range(len(targetPrediksi))
    nilaiTarget = pd.concat([target, targetPrediksi], axis =1)
    for i in range(len(nilaiTarget.index)):
        targetPrediksi.loc[i, 'Hepatitis A '] = targetPrediksi.loc[i, 1]
        targetPrediksi.loc[i, 'Hepatitis A '] = targetPrediksi.loc[i, -1]
    return nilaiTarget
```

and output was "Too Many Indexers"

am i wrong wrote a syntax ? anyway thx for help^^

Comment: better use: `df['Klasifikasi'].replace({'Hepatitis A':1,'Hepatitis B':-1})`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def nilaiPrediksi():
    df = pd.read_csv("datalatihnodummy.csv", sep=';')
    target = df.loc[:5, "Klasifikasi"]
    targetPrediksi = target.sort_index(ascending = False)
    targetPrediksi.index=range(len(targetPrediksi))
    nilaiTarget = pd.concat([target, targetPrediksi], axis =1)
    nilaiTarget['Klasifikasi'] = nilaiTarget['Klasifikasi'].replace({'Hepatitis A': 1, 'Hepatitis B': -1})
    return nilaiTarget
```

Output:

```
   Klasifikasi  Klasifikasi
0            1           -1
1            1           -1
2            1           -1
3           -1            1
4           -1            1
5           -1            1
```

Comment: no problem. please accept the answer if it solved your problem